# Showing a popup message in reactjs if session login fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some functions in my react apps App.js that handle users opening other endpoints apart from login screens unless the user has an active session. The user can access those endpoints immediately if opens my page from any endpoint. So if the user hasn't logged in they will be directed to the login page.  This is my App.js return function and this is how I manage different pages.

```js
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={StudentLogin} />
      <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminLogin} />
      <Route exact path="/student/app" component={StudentApp} />
      <Route exact path="/admin/app" component={AdminApp} />
    </Switch>
  );
```

Here is part of my cookie handling part of the App.js

```js
          if (data != null) {

            var expiration = new Date(data.ExpireDate)
            admin = data.IsAdmin;

            if (new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) <= expiration.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) {

              if (admin) {
                history.push('/admin/app');
              } else {
                history.push('/student/app');
              }

            } else {
              // Session expired. Delete cookies and push login page
              console.log("Session Expired");

              relogin();
            }
          } else {
            // Session login failed (User has logged in from different device). Delete cookies and push login page
            console.log("Session login failed");
            relogin();
          }
```

I want to display the user a message if the session login failed but I have no idea how to do that. I use these functions in app.js since it is called every time the app loads or reloads. How would I achieve either a popup message or display a `<p></p>` block in AdminLogin and StudentLogin in case the login fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use :

```js
alert("I am an alert box!");
```

it's a Simple way to handle it ,

but you can use package like : reactjs-popup

```
yarn add reactjs-popup
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import Popup from 'reactjs-popup';
import 'reactjs-popup/dist/index.css';
 
export default () => (
  <Popup trigger={<button> Trigger</button>} position="right center">
    <div>Popup content here !!</div>
  </Popup>
);
```

I hope ,this can help you

Comment: Thank you! I tried to use the react-popup but I wasn't able to make it work

Comment: i think it is better to use sample

Comment: because reactjs-popup need to make component and take more time

Comment: if u want to use reactjs-popup , first make component and return it